# Reading string from a text file and returning the number of occurrences of each substring of length k

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, bioinformatics

This program takes a simple nucleotide sequence and finds the most common "k-mers" in the sequence, as determined by the supplied dataset (see below). The goal of the program is to find the origin of replication of a DNA sequence, as it is presumably the most common sequence, or in other words, the substring with the most occurrences.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>

//-------------------------------------------
//FUNCTION PROTYPES
//Dataset files include k in them
//void chooseK();

//Open file and read sequence
void enterFileToOpen();
void openFile();
void readFile();

//Generate substrings and save them to file
void enterOFileName();
void openOFile();
void printSubstrToFile();

//Count substrings and determine modal substrings
//Step 1: Open substring output file
//Step 2: Read and aggregate substrings
void setOutPutReadFiletoOutputFile();
void openOutputFile();
void countSubStrings();


//---------------------------------
//VARIABLES
std::string sequence;
int k;

int kmerCount;
int i=0;
std::string subStrPrint;

std::ifstream inFile;
std::string fileName;

std::ofstream outFile;
std::string ofileName;

std::ifstream outputReadFile;
std::string outputReadFileName;

std::map<std::string, int> subSequenceCountMap;
std::string stringMapElement;

//------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    enterFileToOpen();
    openFile();
    readFile();

    enterOFileName();
    openOFile();
    printSubstrToFile();

    setOutPutReadFiletoOutputFile();
    openOutputFile();
    countSubStrings();

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}

void enterFileToOpen()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter file to open: (remember to include full filepath if file is not located within this program's directory)" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> fileName;
    std::cout << "File: " << fileName << std::endl;
}


void openFile()
{
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    //Check for Error during file open process
    if(inFile.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error during Open File Process" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}


void readFile()
{
    inFile >> sequence >> k;

    std::cout << "\nNucleotide sequence: " << sequence << "\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "k = " << k << std::endl;

}

void enterOFileName()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter name for nucleotide subsequence output file: ";
    std::cin >> ofileName;
    std::cout << "Nucleotide subsequence output file: " << ofileName << std::endl;
}

void openOFile()
{
    outFile.open(ofileName.c_str());
}

void printSubstrToFile()
{
    //variables declared globally: kmerCount, i, subStrPrint
    kmerCount = sequence.length()-k;

    i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<kmerCount; i++)
    {
        subStrPrint = sequence.substr(i,k);
        outFile << subStrPrint << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Iteration " << i+1 << ": sub-sequence " << subStrPrint << std::endl;
    }

    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
}

void setOutPutReadFiletoOutputFile()
{
    //No need to specify file path for read file, since we just created it
    outputReadFileName = ofileName;
}

void openOutputFile()
{
    inFile.open(outputReadFileName.c_str());

    //Check for Errors
    if(inFile.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error during File Open" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nFile opened successfully\n" << std::endl;
    }
}

void countSubStrings()
{
    i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < kmerCount; i++)
    {
        inFile >> stringMapElement;

        if(subSequenceCountMap.find(stringMapElement)!=subSequenceCountMap.end())
        {
            subSequenceCountMap[stringMapElement]++;
        }
        else
        {
            subSequenceCountMap[stringMapElement]=1;
        }
    }

    for (std::map<std::string, int>::iterator itr = subSequenceCountMap.begin(); itr!=subSequenceCountMap.end(); ++itr) //changed const_iterator to iterator, cbegin to begin, cend to end
    {
        if(itr->second >1)
        {
            std::cout << itr->first << " occurs " << itr->second << " times" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << itr->first << " occurs " << itr->second << " time" << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Sample dataset:

```
TGAATAGGAATCCCAACGTCTTGTGAATAGGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAACGTCTTGTGCAAGGTGCAAGGGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAACGTCTTGTGCAAGGGAATCCCAACGTCTTGTGGCCTAGAATCCCAACGTCTTGGAATCCCAACGTCTTGGAATCCCAATGCAAGGGAATCCCAACGTCTTGTGCAAGGTGCAAGGTGAATAGCGTCTTGGAATCCCAATGCAAGGTGGCCTATGCAAGGTGAATAGTGAATAGTGGCCTATGGCCTATGCAAGGTGCAAGGTGAATAGTGCAAGGGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAATGAATAGGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAATGGCCTATGGCCTACGTCTTGTGCAAGGTGGCCTACGTCTTGGAATCCCAATGCAAGGGAATCCCAATGAATAGTGCAAGGGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAATGCAAGGTGGCCTATGCAAGGCGTCTTGCGTCTTGTGGCCTATGCAAGGGAATCCCAATGCAAGGGAATCCCAATGCAAGGTGCAAGGTGCAAGGGAATCCCAACGTCTTGGAATCCCAACGTCTTGCGTCTTGGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAATGGCCTACGTCTTGGAATCCCAATGCAAGGTGAATAGTGAATAGGAATCCCAATGGCCTACGTCTTGTGGCCTATGAATAGTGAATAGTGGCCTAGAATCCCAATGAATAGGAATCCCAATGGCCTACGTCTTGTGCAAGGTGCAAGGTGGCCTACGTCTTGCGTCTTGGAATCCCAAGAATCCCAATGCAAGGTGGCCTATGGCCTATGAATAGTGCAAGGGAATCCCAACGTCTTGCGTCTTGCGTCTTGGAATCCCAA
12
```

When this file is entered into the program, the program will generate every possible substring of length 12 and calculate the occurrence of each distinct one.

Sample data set output:

```
AACGTCTTGCGT occurs 2 times
AACGTCTTGGAA occurs 3 times
AACGTCTTGTGA occurs 1 time
AACGTCTTGTGC occurs 3 times
AACGTCTTGTGG occurs 1 time
AAGAATCCCAAC occurs 2 times
AAGAATCCCAAG occurs 3 times
AAGAATCCCAAT occurs 5 times
AAGGCGTCTTGC occurs 1 time
AAGGGAATCCCA occurs 10 times
AAGGTGAATAGC occurs 1 time
AAGGTGAATAGT occurs 3 times
AAGGTGCAAGGG occurs 2 times
AAGGTGCAAGGT occurs 4 times
AAGGTGGCCTAC occurs 2 times
AAGGTGGCCTAT occurs 3 times
AATAGCGTCTTG occurs 1 time
AATAGGAATCCC occurs 5 times
AATAGTGAATAG occurs 3 times
AATAGTGCAAGG occurs 3 times
AATAGTGGCCTA occurs 2 times
AATCCCAACGTC occurs 10 times
AATCCCAAGAAT occurs 10 times
AATCCCAATGAA occurs 3 times
AATCCCAATGCA occurs 8 times
AATCCCAATGGC occurs 4 times
AATGAATAGGAA occurs 2 times
AATGAATAGTGC occurs 1 time
AATGCAAGGGAA occurs 3 times
AATGCAAGGTGA occurs 1 time
AATGCAAGGTGC occurs 1 time
AATGCAAGGTGG occurs 3 times
AATGGCCTACGT occurs 3 times
AATGGCCTATGG occurs 1 time
ACGTCTTGCGTC occurs 3 times
ACGTCTTGGAAT occurs 5 times
ACGTCTTGTGAA occurs 1 time
ACGTCTTGTGCA occurs 5 times
ACGTCTTGTGGC occurs 2 times
AGAATCCCAACG occurs 3 times
AGAATCCCAAGA occurs 3 times
AGAATCCCAATG occurs 6 times
AGCGTCTTGGAA occurs 1 time
AGGAATCCCAAC occurs 1 time
AGGAATCCCAAG occurs 2 times
AGGAATCCCAAT occurs 2 times
AGGCGTCTTGCG occurs 1 time
AGGGAATCCCAA occurs 10 times
AGGTGAATAGCG occurs 1 time
AGGTGAATAGTG occurs 3 times
AGGTGCAAGGGA occurs 2 times
AGGTGCAAGGTG occurs 4 times
AGGTGGCCTACG occurs 2 times
AGGTGGCCTATG occurs 3 times
AGTGAATAGGAA occurs 1 time
AGTGAATAGTGG occurs 2 times
AGTGCAAGGGAA occurs 3 times
AGTGGCCTAGAA occurs 1 time
AGTGGCCTATGG occurs 1 time
ATAGCGTCTTGG occurs 1 time
ATAGGAATCCCA occurs 5 times
ATAGTGAATAGG occurs 1 time
ATAGTGAATAGT occurs 2 times
ATAGTGCAAGGG occurs 3 times
ATAGTGGCCTAG occurs 1 time
ATAGTGGCCTAT occurs 1 time
ATCCCAACGTCT occurs 10 times
ATCCCAAGAATC occurs 10 times
ATCCCAATGAAT occurs 3 times
ATCCCAATGCAA occurs 8 times
ATCCCAATGGCC occurs 4 times
ATGAATAGGAAT occurs 2 times
ATGAATAGTGAA occurs 1 time
ATGAATAGTGCA occurs 2 times
ATGCAAGGCGTC occurs 1 time
ATGCAAGGGAAT occurs 4 times
ATGCAAGGTGAA occurs 2 times
ATGCAAGGTGCA occurs 2 times
ATGCAAGGTGGC occurs 3 times
ATGGCCTACGTC occurs 4 times
ATGGCCTATGAA occurs 1 time
ATGGCCTATGCA occurs 1 time
ATGGCCTATGGC occurs 1 time
CAACGTCTTGCG occurs 2 times
CAACGTCTTGGA occurs 3 times
CAACGTCTTGTG occurs 5 times
CAAGAATCCCAA occurs 10 times
CAAGGCGTCTTG occurs 1 time
CAAGGGAATCCC occurs 10 times
CAAGGTGAATAG occurs 4 times
CAAGGTGCAAGG occurs 6 times
CAAGGTGGCCTA occurs 5 times
CAATGAATAGGA occurs 2 times
CAATGAATAGTG occurs 1 time
CAATGCAAGGGA occurs 3 times
CAATGCAAGGTG occurs 5 times
CAATGGCCTACG occurs 3 times
CAATGGCCTATG occurs 1 time
CCAACGTCTTGC occurs 2 times
CCAACGTCTTGG occurs 3 times
CCAACGTCTTGT occurs 5 times
CCAAGAATCCCA occurs 10 times
CCAATGAATAGG occurs 2 times
CCAATGAATAGT occurs 1 time
CCAATGCAAGGG occurs 3 times
CCAATGCAAGGT occurs 5 times
CCAATGGCCTAC occurs 3 times
CCAATGGCCTAT occurs 1 time
CCCAACGTCTTG occurs 10 times
CCCAAGAATCCC occurs 10 times
CCCAATGAATAG occurs 3 times
CCCAATGCAAGG occurs 8 times
CCCAATGGCCTA occurs 4 times
CCTACGTCTTGC occurs 1 time
CCTACGTCTTGG occurs 2 times
CCTACGTCTTGT occurs 3 times
CCTAGAATCCCA occurs 2 times
CCTATGAATAGT occurs 2 times
CCTATGCAAGGC occurs 1 time
CCTATGCAAGGG occurs 1 time
CCTATGCAAGGT occurs 2 times
CCTATGGCCTAC occurs 1 time
CCTATGGCCTAT occurs 2 times
CGTCTTGCGTCT occurs 5 times
CGTCTTGGAATC occurs 9 times
CGTCTTGTGAAT occurs 1 time
CGTCTTGTGCAA occurs 5 times
CGTCTTGTGGCC occurs 3 times
CTACGTCTTGCG occurs 1 time
CTACGTCTTGGA occurs 2 times
CTACGTCTTGTG occurs 3 times
CTAGAATCCCAA occurs 2 times
CTATGAATAGTG occurs 2 times
CTATGCAAGGCG occurs 1 time
CTATGCAAGGGA occurs 1 time
CTATGCAAGGTG occurs 2 times
CTATGGCCTACG occurs 1 time
CTATGGCCTATG occurs 2 times
CTTGCGTCTTGC occurs 1 time
CTTGCGTCTTGG occurs 3 times
CTTGCGTCTTGT occurs 1 time
CTTGGAATCCCA occurs 9 times
CTTGTGAATAGG occurs 1 time
CTTGTGCAAGGG occurs 1 time
CTTGTGCAAGGT occurs 4 times
CTTGTGGCCTAG occurs 1 time
CTTGTGGCCTAT occurs 2 times
GAATAGCGTCTT occurs 1 time
GAATAGGAATCC occurs 5 times
GAATAGTGAATA occurs 3 times
GAATAGTGCAAG occurs 3 times
GAATAGTGGCCT occurs 2 times
GAATCCCAACGT occurs 10 times
GAATCCCAAGAA occurs 10 times
GAATCCCAATGA occurs 3 times
GAATCCCAATGC occurs 8 times
GAATCCCAATGG occurs 4 times
GCAAGGCGTCTT occurs 1 time
GCAAGGGAATCC occurs 10 times
GCAAGGTGAATA occurs 4 times
GCAAGGTGCAAG occurs 6 times
GCAAGGTGGCCT occurs 5 times
GCCTACGTCTTG occurs 6 times
GCCTAGAATCCC occurs 2 times
GCCTATGAATAG occurs 2 times
GCCTATGCAAGG occurs 4 times
GCCTATGGCCTA occurs 3 times
GCGTCTTGCGTC occurs 2 times
GCGTCTTGGAAT occurs 4 times
GCGTCTTGTGGC occurs 1 time
GGAATCCCAACG occurs 7 times
GGAATCCCAAGA occurs 7 times
GGAATCCCAATG occurs 9 times
GGCCTACGTCTT occurs 6 times
GGCCTAGAATCC occurs 2 times
GGCCTATGAATA occurs 2 times
GGCCTATGCAAG occurs 4 times
GGCCTATGGCCT occurs 3 times
GGCGTCTTGCGT occurs 1 time
GGGAATCCCAAC occurs 4 times
GGGAATCCCAAG occurs 3 times
GGGAATCCCAAT occurs 3 times
GGTGAATAGCGT occurs 1 time
GGTGAATAGTGA occurs 2 times
GGTGAATAGTGC occurs 1 time
GGTGCAAGGGAA occurs 2 times
GGTGCAAGGTGA occurs 2 times
GGTGCAAGGTGC occurs 1 time
GGTGCAAGGTGG occurs 1 time
GGTGGCCTACGT occurs 2 times
GGTGGCCTATGC occurs 2 times
GGTGGCCTATGG occurs 1 time
GTCTTGCGTCTT occurs 5 times
GTCTTGGAATCC occurs 9 times
GTCTTGTGAATA occurs 1 time
GTCTTGTGCAAG occurs 5 times
GTCTTGTGGCCT occurs 3 times
GTGAATAGCGTC occurs 1 time
GTGAATAGGAAT occurs 2 times
GTGAATAGTGAA occurs 2 times
GTGAATAGTGCA occurs 1 time
GTGAATAGTGGC occurs 2 times
GTGCAAGGGAAT occurs 6 times
GTGCAAGGTGAA occurs 2 times
GTGCAAGGTGCA occurs 4 times
GTGCAAGGTGGC occurs 2 times
GTGGCCTACGTC occurs 2 times
GTGGCCTAGAAT occurs 2 times
GTGGCCTATGAA occurs 1 time
GTGGCCTATGCA occurs 3 times
GTGGCCTATGGC occurs 2 times
TACGTCTTGCGT occurs 1 time
TACGTCTTGGAA occurs 2 times
TACGTCTTGTGC occurs 2 times
TACGTCTTGTGG occurs 1 time
TAGAATCCCAAC occurs 1 time
TAGAATCCCAAT occurs 1 time
TAGCGTCTTGGA occurs 1 time
TAGGAATCCCAA occurs 5 times
TAGTGAATAGGA occurs 1 time
TAGTGAATAGTG occurs 2 times
TAGTGCAAGGGA occurs 3 times
TAGTGGCCTAGA occurs 1 time
TAGTGGCCTATG occurs 1 time
TATGAATAGTGA occurs 1 time
TATGAATAGTGC occurs 1 time
TATGCAAGGCGT occurs 1 time
TATGCAAGGGAA occurs 1 time
TATGCAAGGTGA occurs 1 time
TATGCAAGGTGC occurs 1 time
TATGGCCTACGT occurs 1 time
TATGGCCTATGA occurs 1 time
TATGGCCTATGC occurs 1 time
TCCCAACGTCTT occurs 10 times
TCCCAAGAATCC occurs 10 times
TCCCAATGAATA occurs 3 times
TCCCAATGCAAG occurs 8 times
TCCCAATGGCCT occurs 4 times
TCTTGCGTCTTG occurs 5 times
TCTTGGAATCCC occurs 9 times
TCTTGTGAATAG occurs 1 time
TCTTGTGCAAGG occurs 5 times
TCTTGTGGCCTA occurs 3 times
TGAATAGCGTCT occurs 1 time
TGAATAGGAATC occurs 5 times
TGAATAGTGAAT occurs 3 times
TGAATAGTGCAA occurs 3 times
TGAATAGTGGCC occurs 2 times
TGCAAGGCGTCT occurs 1 time
TGCAAGGGAATC occurs 10 times
TGCAAGGTGAAT occurs 4 times
TGCAAGGTGCAA occurs 6 times
TGCAAGGTGGCC occurs 5 times
TGCGTCTTGCGT occurs 1 time
TGCGTCTTGGAA occurs 3 times
TGCGTCTTGTGG occurs 1 time
TGGAATCCCAAC occurs 2 times
TGGAATCCCAAG occurs 2 times
TGGAATCCCAAT occurs 4 times
TGGCCTACGTCT occurs 6 times
TGGCCTAGAATC occurs 2 times
TGGCCTATGAAT occurs 2 times
TGGCCTATGCAA occurs 4 times
TGGCCTATGGCC occurs 3 times
TGTGAATAGGAA occurs 1 time
TGTGCAAGGGAA occurs 1 time
TGTGCAAGGTGC occurs 3 times
TGTGCAAGGTGG occurs 1 time
TGTGGCCTAGAA occurs 1 time
TGTGGCCTATGA occurs 1 time
TGTGGCCTATGC occurs 1 time
TTGCGTCTTGCG occurs 1 time
TTGCGTCTTGGA occurs 3 times
TTGCGTCTTGTG occurs 1 time
TTGGAATCCCAA occurs 8 times
TTGTGAATAGGA occurs 1 time
TTGTGCAAGGGA occurs 1 time
TTGTGCAAGGTG occurs 4 times
TTGTGGCCTAGA occurs 1 time
TTGTGGCCTATG occurs 2 times
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Code Review

Replace:

```
    if(subSequenceCountMap.find(stringMapElement)!=subSequenceCountMap.end())
    {
        subSequenceCountMap[stringMapElement]++;
    }
    else
    {
        subSequenceCountMap[stringMapElement]=1;
    }
```

With:

```
    subSequenceCountMap[stringMapElement]++;
```

This is because `operator[]` will automatically insert the element `0` if it does not already exist before returning a reference. Thus if you just increment the value you get the correct result.

I don't see the point of using an intermediate file to store all the sub strings. Just put them dirextly into the map.

Replace:

```
for(i=0; i<kmerCount; i++)
{
    subStrPrint = sequence.substr(i,k);
    outFile << subStrPrint << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Iteration " << i+1 << ": sub-sequence " << subStrPrint << std::endl;
}
```

With:

```
for(i=0; i<kmerCount; i++)
{
    subSequenceCountMap[sequence.substr(i,k)]++;
}
```

Not sure why you need this test:

```
    if(itr->second >1)
    {
        std::cout << itr->first << " occurs " << itr->second << " times" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << itr->first << " occurs " << itr->second << " time" << std::endl;
    }
```

Both sides of the `if statement` are exactly the same. Remove all the ones that have only happened once by removing the whole else block!

Ohh. I see it now. The extra `s` on the end of `time`. Yea. If this were a million dollar project maybe I would go to the extra effort of pluralization. But I would do it simpler.

```
    std::cout << itr->first << " occurs "
              << itr->second << " time" << ((itr->second > 1)?"s":"")
              << "\n";
```

### Design:

Don't use global variables.

```
//---------------------------------
//VARIABLES
std::string sequence;
int k;

int kmerCount;
int i=0;
std::string subStrPrint;

std::ifstream inFile;
std::string fileName;

std::ofstream outFile;
std::string ofileName;

std::ifstream outputReadFile;
std::string outputReadFileName;

std::map<std::string, int> subSequenceCountMap;
std::string stringMapElement;
```

Have local variables and pass them as parameters to functions and get results as a return value from the function.

Loading the whole gene into memory seems like it could be very expensive. Especially since you only need the `k` characters at a time. Why not load the first `k` characters (that's your first string). Then move everything down once then read one more character to the end.

### Error

You have an off by one error here:

```
 kmerCount = sequence.length()-k;
```

Your code reports:

```
 TTGGAATCCCAA occurrs 8 times
```

But if you manually count it. You will find that it happens 9 times.

### Writting in C++ style

I would have used an object to encapsulate the gene fragment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Gene
{
    std::istream&   in;
    std::string     section;
    public:
        Gene(std::istream& in, std::size_t size)
            : in(in)
        {
            section.resize(size);
            in.read(&section[0], size);
        }

        bool more()
        {
            return in.good();
        }

        void next()
        {
            std::move(std::begin(section) + 1, std::end(section), std::begin(section));
            in.read(&section.back(), 1);
        }
        operator std::string const&()
        {
            return section;
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::string fileName;
    std::size_t size;

    std::cout << "Enter File Name with Gene and size\n";
    if (!(std::cin >> fileName >> size))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read info\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream   file(fileName);
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::map<std::string, int>  count;
    for(Gene gene(file, size);gene.more();gene.next())
    {
        ++count[gene];
    }

    for(auto const& item: count)
    {
        if (item.second > 1)
        {
            std::cout << item.first << " " << item.second << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my program. I think it's pretty funny that I never stopped using global variables since I started doing it while I was learning Visual Basic in '05-'06. I don't think I ever would have realized it was wrong if you hadn't pointed it out, although I must admit it felt weird doing it. Thank you again, that was truly insightful.

You recommended encapsulating the gene fragment using an object, but I must admit I'm a bit at a loss as to how to do that right now, but having your template for the main function for now helped me out a lot.

Comment: I especially liked your mention of not loading the entire gene into memory. I hadn't considered the performance repercussions, about which you're absolutely right. The sample dataset I used for this project wasn't even a tenth of the size of a real sequence, so thank you for that.

Thank you again for the review, it was remarkably enlightening. Happy holidays, Jose

Comment: @JoseLopez Added the Gene class for you.

Comment: Probably want to write errors to `std:cerr`, and `return 1;` instead of `exit(1);` (`exit` doesn't guarantee flushing output streams, among other things).

Comment: @JerryCoffin That makes sense, I didn't know that, thank you